# Is there a software package that allows users to create map tiles?

Tags: tiles, aerial-photography, software-recommendations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

We would like to create map tiles to be used via mobile device in the field in an offline environment.  The imagery will come from our personal collection of aerial images taken via UAV.

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html

Comment: I think more information is necessary; What is your source? Do you want to just tile an existing image, or tile it according to some specific tiling system? What will it be used for? Are you looking to use it in some specific software?

Comment: The data images are captured via point and shoot camera appended to a UAV.  The tiles will ultimately be used for multi-spectral analysis in addition to mobile device rendering.

Answer (score 5):

Please check out http://www.klokantech.com/maptiler/ very good software to create tiles from images.

Comment: @GeoffreyWest My pleasure :) did you manage to create tiles using maptiler.

Comment: giving it a shot now!

Comment: Maptiler is great. It is very easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

**TileMill** from MapBox is designed to be code free as possible.

There are some impressive tiles in the gallery
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/gallery/#kkaefer.iceland

There are 4 steps:

**Import Data**

**Style your data** (time consuming)

**Add interactivity**

**Export Map** (MBtiles, PNG, SVG)

Documentation
https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/

Answer (score 2):

The following tutorials might be useful:

1. Creating tiles with ImageMagick or https://github.com/rktjmp/tileup
   : http://omarriott.com/aux/leaflet-js-non-geographical-imagery/
2. Creating tiles with GDAL: http://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/general/zoomable-image-with-gdal-and-leaflet